# Redirect PHP to new window

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a PHP file reports.php that has a form which when clicked submit goes to reports6.php.

reports6.php has the code for mysql, if rows are not found it is redirected back to reports.php with the error code.

In reports6.php I am using to go to reports.php

```
header ("location: reports.php")
```

However if rows are found if sets some parameters and calls another php file (cpdf.php) to create the pdf from those parameters using header redirect again.

What I want is when the user clicks submit from reports.php .. cpdf.php should open in new page.

if I use target="_blank" in reports.php while submitting form report6.php opens in another tab and pdf gets generated but if there are no rows reports.php is opened in another tab saying "no rows found".

If i dont use _blank in reports.php and use javascript in reports6.php to open the cpdf.php and header redirect to reports.php it doesn't work (i have given allow pop-ups but I dont know why the cpdf.php won't open)..

If i give some output in reports6.php like "echo me;" then the pdf opens fine.. i suppose that has to do with the sequence of php and the  or something.

As i searched other previously asked questions there is no way to use header and open in new tab in php..

So what can I do in this case?

Thanks.

## edit:

Here is the relevant code:

Reports.php

```
<form name="report6" action="report6.php" onsubmit="return check_digit('report6','system_id',' System ID ')"method="post">
        <td><b>Print old Invoice by System ID: </b></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="system_id" ></td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="Run" value="Run"></td>
</form>
```

Reports6.php

```
$sql=blah blah blah
if ( $row_cnt == 0 ) 
    { 
        $mysqloutput="No such System ID in the Database";
        $_SESSION["mysqloutput"]=$mysqloutput; 
        mysqli_close($con);
        die(header ("location: reports.php"));
    }
else
{ header ("location: cpdf.php"); }
```

cpdf.php

//The code to generate the pdf

What I have tried:

1) Add target="_blank" in reports.php

2) Add `<script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript">window.open("cpdf.php")</script>` in reports6.php

What I want:

cpdf.php opens in new tab when form is submitted from reports.php if rows are there

if not redirects back to reports.php in the same tab only (not in another tab as I get it)

Comment: since this was also tag as javascript.. why not create a request to check if the submitted values has result before it creates a new window for you.. use ajax..

Answer (score 3):

You cannot open a new window in PHP because it is server side scripting. You could however add an indicator to your header location when you want it to be opened in a new window as so:

```
header("Location: reports.php?newwindow=true"); exit();
```

and on your reports.php file, you could pick that GET method up, and check if it is set, and force the window to be opened in a new window using javascript.

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['newwindow']) && $_GET['newwindow']=="true"){ ?>
<script>[... script that handles new window here ...]</script>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the lead.. I will just set a $_SESSION variable in report6.php and check for it in reports.php to echo out the <script> part, and then unset it.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to open a new window using php here is the correct code

```
echo "<script language=\"javascript\">window.open('cpdf.php',\"_blank\");</script>";
```